# Does your Android Compass hardware work while driving or beeing in a train?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, compass-geolocation, digital-compass

I have a Desire Z and when moving to fast the compass hardware starts to return totally wrong values. Its probably the hardware which can't measure correctly when moving to fast but i want to know if all devices have this problem.

You can try it with your own phone by installing any compass app (don't use Google Maps cause they switch automatically to GPS-compass-mode when moving). 
I need to know this because for Augmented Reality applications its still relevant to know where the user is looking when being in a train/car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't even expect a conventional magnetic compass to work correctly in the steel cage that is a car. On an train that draws electric power through the third rail, I've seen the dial flip through 180 degrees as it draws current on acceleration.

Comment: Ok good point, the energy supply in trains might have caused the strange behavior last time. Today I tested the behavior in a driving car and there wasn't any problem with the compass.

Answer (score 1):

Compasses generally work fine in cars; several manufacturers make them and they just need to avoid the engine bay, window motors, and rear-window defrosters.

Trains on the other hand...as a usual metro (electric) and intercity train (diesel) rider, compasses are near-as-makes-no-difference useless.  From some testing I did with a module from JCI (automotive supplier) in a car, driving over railroad crossings throws a compass into disarray.  The control module that read from the compass had an in-built glitch filter to discard such radical changes in orientation (which somehow is [patentable](http://www.google.com/patents/US6301794)).